# Where can I download Yahoo's Geoplanet Data?

Tags: data, geoplanet, yahoo

I was trying to Download the Yahoo Geoplanet Data, so that my application does not have a dependency on the [API provided](https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/) by Yahoo.

When I go to the [download link](https://developer.yahoo.com/geo/geoplanet/data/), I see the following message:

> We are currently making the data non-downloadable while we determine a better way to surface the data as a part of the service.

Since this data was originally shared with a [CC BY 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/) license, there should be someone who is hosting this data, and offers it for download.

Where can I download the actual data?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thankfully, the Internet Archive has archived this data, and offers it for download. All the different versions are tagged with the [geoplanet keyword](http://archive.org/search.php?query=geoplanet).

The latest version available is 7.10.0 and can be [downloaded from this](https://archive.org/details/geoplanet_data_7.10.0.zip) page.